# Word wrap when using git grep

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I am trying to run git grep from terminal (using Titanium).  The results do not wrap and get cut off at the window so I cannot read anything. I tried messing around with config but could not get anything.  How can I make these grep results wrap?

Comment: The `-e` parameter of git grep can be useful here. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979537/6309)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you set `core.pager` in your `.gitconfig`? If you are using `less`, you can see the extra characters by pressing the right arrow key on the keyboard.

**Edit:** Even when I unset `core.pager`, `git grep` seems to invoke `less -S` by default.

**Edit 2:** Whoops, as Keith Thompson pointed out `less` does wrap lines by default. From the man page:

> ```
>    -S or --chop-long-lines
>           Causes lines longer than the screen width to be  chopped  rather
>           than  folded.  That is, the portion of a long line that does not
>           fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default  is  to  fold
>           long lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.
> ```

Comment: And in `less`, `-S` toggles between wrapping and truncating.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I use `-S` so I thought this behavior was default. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: If you actually want to modify the behavior, the right way is to set the `LESS` environment variable. If it's unset, Git defaults to `FRSX`. `F` makes it automatically exit if there's less than a screen, `X` makes it work right with that (avoids messing with scrollback), and `R` makes it show colors. So you'd probably want to use `LESS=FRX` to avoid messing anything else up.

Answer (score 4):

Try piping the output through `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

With a pager like less, [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) was already able to pass options to said pager:

```
-e
```

> The next parameter is the pattern.
>   This option has to be used for patterns starting with `-` and should be used in scripts passing user input to grep.

Starting git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), that also also work with case insensitive `git grep`.

See [commit f7febbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7febbea07cf6d65f85b0cdb6684d2e3666c557e) from [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho):

#### `git grep -O -i`: if the pager is '`less`', pass the '`-I`' option

> When `<command>` happens to be the magic string "`less`", today

```
git grep -O<command> -e<pattern>
```

> helpfully passes `+/<pattern>` to less so you can navigate through the results within a file using the <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> keystrokes.

Alas, that doesn't do the right thing for a case-insensitive match,
i.e.

```
git grep -i -O<command> -e<pattern>
```

> For that case we should pass `--IGNORE-CASE` to "`less`" so that <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> can move between results ignoring case in the pattern.
>
> The original patch came from msysgit and used "`-i`", but that was not due to lack of support for "`-I`" but it merely overlooked that it ought to work even when the pattern contains capital letters.